# Problems migrating angular app from localhost to live server

Tags: angularjs, server, localhost

I'm stuck with a weird behavior of my app.
It's a simple 'crud' application with the usual create, read, update and delete operations. 
I have developed it with AngularJS in localhost and all is working as it should.
Now I have published it on a live server, but strange enough the update and delete operations fail to work. Read and create: no problem.

Console reports: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)'

I can't figure out why all is working well on localhost, but on a live server only read and create. Update and delete fail. Why is there a difference between localhost and live server?
Where do I start my search for  getting a solution?

Answer (score 0):

That means you have to grant permission. there is nothing wrong in the app. Set it to 644

Comment: @ Krishna Kamal: All folders in the directory has permission 755, however all the files inside these folders have permission set to 644. Now i'm confused what to do.